# Consuming a web service using Visual Studio 10 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I need to call a web service using Visual Studio and C#. I have already created a configuration file and a client to call the service, but I keep getting an exception:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1: Oracle Connection is not successful.

As I have not really worked with ASP.NET applications and web services much, I am not sure how to fix this, and whether it's due to my mistake or because something is wrong with the created web service itself.

I have used the following to call the service:

```
ServiceReference.InformationClient client = new ServiceReference.InformationClient();
client.GetInformation("123");
client.close();
```

`GetInformation` is the Web Service Name, with an input parameter ID of type string, and returns a data set of user name, surname, and age.

This is the stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
Message=Oracle Connection is not successful
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: 
   at   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsumingWebService.ServiceReference.IInformation.GetInformation(String ID)
   at ConsumingWebService.ServiceReference.InformationClient.GetInformation(String ID) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsumingWebService\ConsumingWebService\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 53
   at ConsumingWebService.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsumingWebService\ConsumingWebService\Program.cs:line 13
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I edited with adding the full stack trace of the error. Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your service and put some breakpoint inside your GetInformation method? Try to attached process to w3wp in your visual studio. It might happened that you have problem in your code about connecting to your oracle database.

Comment: The problem is I don't have an access to web service methods, as it was created for me by another colleague.

Answer (score 0):

[FaultException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

FaultExceptions in the WCF world are used as a method of communicating server errors/exceptions across the WCF channel.

In your case, it appears as though the web service you are attempting to consume is having problems connecting to a required database.

Comment: I'm not sure this tells us anything we didn't already know, nor how to fix it

Comment: This is a server side error. With access only to the client side, there isn't anything we can do about it beyond handling the exception.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Unfortunately I don't have the access to the server side .